# Generator Function Always Yielding The Same Thing Twice

Tags: python, generator, yield

I have this generator function that I wish to sift through a dataset of images with. The images are in a PyTorch dataloader with a batch size of 16. I loop over the dataloader to grab a batch (16 images), then loop over the batch to grab an image.

What I want to do is to store the image labels in images and `yield` that, while plotting the 16 images on the figure. So I want to do `images = next(show_batch(dataloader, labels_dataframe, nrows, ncols))` and everytime I get 16 image labels stored in images and a plot of 16 images. This way I can identify bad images and have their labels ready to discard from my dataset. The code keeps generating the same (first) 16 images twice. I suspect it has to do with making a new list everytime so I am restarting the generator?

Why does the code keep generating the same 16 images twice after each other and how do I fix it to generate 16 images at a time while storing their labels taken from the `labels_dataframe` in images?

```
def show_batch(dataloader, labels_dataframe, nrows, ncols):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(30,15))
    for i, batch in enumerate(train_dl):
        images = []
        for j, image in enumerate(batch['image']):
            ax = fig.add_subplot(nrows, ncols, j+1)
            ax.imshow(image.permute(2, 1, 0))
            images.append(labels_dataframe.loc[i*16+j, 'id_code'])
        yield images
```

Comment: You should show how you're calling this generator too, you could be using it wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

Marco Bonelli pointed out that I should show how I am calling the generator. While I went to do that, I discovered what I have been doing wrong, and fixed how I call it and the function.

I was calling `next(show_batch(dataloader, labels_dataframe, nrows, ncols))` and so was calling a new generator function every time. I didn't make a generator object.

Then when I made a generator object and started calling it, it only showed the first 16 images then was yielding only the labels after that, so I moved the figure object to inside every batch loop. The revised code and how I call it:

```
def show_batch(dataloader, labels_dataframe, nrows, ncols):
    for i, batch in enumerate(train_dl):
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(30,15))
        images = []
        for j, image in enumerate(batch['image']):
            ax = fig.add_subplot(nrows, ncols, j+1)
            ax.imshow(image.permute(2, 1, 0))
            images.append(labels_dataframe.loc[i*16+j, 'id_code'])
        yield images

sample_images = show_batch(dataloader, labels_dataframe, nrows, ncols)
next(sample_images)
```

Thanks, Marco.